# Динамическое добавление html объектов

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте!Уже пару месяцев волнует вопрос, как ПРАВИЛЬНО добавлять html код (к примеру php файлом)? И как их обрабатывать через PHP? Подскажите пожалуйста, или натолкните на литературу

```
echo "<table class='table table-hover' >
<thead class='thead-dark'>
<!--Здесь громадные куски html кода-->
</thead>
<tbody> <tr ><td><form >
<input type='hidden' name='title' value=$value /><input type='hidden' name='add_task'/>
<input type='hidden' name='table_id' value=".$users->id."/>
<input type='submit' value='Add Task'/>
</form></td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: они генерируются с помощью циклов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартная Controller->View схема, если говорить просто, то

Вы разделяете Серверный код и клиентский код по разным файлам. Наиболее простой пример:

**файл html.php** Содержит минимальное количество серверного кода, в основном там используется код для вывода данных, в данном случае единственным данными у нас есть `$users->id`.

```
<table class='table table-hover' >
<thead class='thead-dark'>
<!--Здесь громадные куски html кода-->
</thead>
<tbody> <tr ><td><form >
<input type='hidden' name='title' value=$value /><input type='hidden' name='add_task'/>
<input type='hidden' name='table_id' value="<?=$users->id?>"/>
<input type='submit' value='Add Task'/>
</form></td></tr></table>
```

**файл php.php**

```
$user->id = '1234';
include ('html.php');
```

Подобная схема используется повсеместно, но разумеется она сложнее, чем то, что показано в примере. Гуглите MVC (Model - Controller - View), чтобы ознакомиться с этим принципом подробнее.

Comment: спасибо) это то, что я хотела узнать